# Java: Launch4J and choosing a compatible JRE

Tags: java

I am trying to create an Executable for my Java dekstop application so people without JRE can run it. I am doing this for the first time and if I understand correctly, the steps are as follows:

1. Produce a .jar file
2. Create a JRE folder (which I can do by just copying the
   contents of my local java jre folder)
3. Use Launch4J to create an .exe file that uses the JRE folder

The resulting .exe file should be executable for everyone as long as the JRE folder is at the path specified in Launch4J.

I did the above and when I try to run the .exe, I get `a jni error has occurred please check your installation and try again`. I did some googleing and found out that this error is most likely caused by an incompatible JRE version / the JRE in the JRE folder being different from what was used to compile the .jar

While developing and also when creating the .jar, I used a JDK - so I tried filling the JRE folder with a JDK instead and then I could run the .exe without a problem.

**So now to the actual question:**

Does this mean I need to create the .jar file somehow using the JRE instead of the JDK (I always assumed while developing I must use the JDK, since its the java DEVELOPMENT kid) ? If yes, how do I configure that in IntelliJ?

Comment: The JDK includes a JRE. You could run the executable since the JRE version from your JDK matched the version you compiled the JAR with. I.e.you should just have to copy the `jre` folder from your JDK directory for things to work. No need to use something else than the JDK for development.

Comment: @TimonNetherlands there does not seem to be a jre folder in my jdk folder, if that is what you meant. Basically I have my Java folder that contains a jdk-15.0.1 folder and a jre1.8.0 folder. Is there a way to find out what jre version my jdk has included?

Comment: excuse me. I forgot I have a customized JDK directory with a `jre` directory which normally is not there. It remains true however that the JDK folder is a superset and contains everything of the JRE. You have two options here: either copy the contents of your JDK folder, as you did, or develop your program against version 1.8 matching your JRE by adding the wanted version to your pom.xml, as shown here (§2.1) : https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way.  If you are using Java 9 or later as your development platform, you should look at the `jlink` command (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html).  It can create an executable with an embed custom JRE that only includes the classes that your application needs.  I also recommend that you use the most recent LTS Java (Java 11) rather that Java 8 or Java 15.  (Java 15 is end-of-life in 3 months time.)

Comment: BTW, the distinction between JRE and JDK was removed in Java 9.  That's why you can't find a "jre" folder in your Java 15 installation.

Comment: one more option https://www.graalvm.org/